# Getting query for OSMquery-Tool using dynamic codeblock

Tags: arcpy, openstreetmap, arcgis-pro, overpass-api

The OSMQuery tool (https://github.com/riccardoklinger/OSMquery/releases/tag/1.0.0) makes a request to Overpass API and returns a layer. The `in_query` makes the request to the Overpass API and must be written in Overpass QL. It is to be passed like a code block. So with `"""code"""`. I like to have the queries generated by algorithm in a later step. For this I need to be able to exchange elements of the query.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

As the script stands it does not work. For it to work #2 must be selected. But this option is static and not dynamic.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Arbeitsordner\OSMquery-1.0.0\OSMquery-1.0.0\OSMQuery.pyt")

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/user/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/BraunDaten/Default.gdb"
#tabelle = "Straßenverzeichnis_osmST_Braunschweig"

#Feld "shape_length" hinzufügen
#arcpy.management.AddField(tabelle, "shape_length", "DOUBLE")

ags_name = "Braunschweig"
str_name = "Celler Heerstraße"
plz = "38114"

semi= """"""
ags_f = f"(area[name={ags_name}];) ->.a;"
plz_f = f"(area[postal_code={plz}];) ->.b;"
str_f = f"way(area.a)(area.b)[name={str_name}];"
in_query = semi + ags_f + plz_f + str_f + semi
# in_query = "\'" + "\'" + "\'" + ags_f + plz_f + str_f + "\'" + "\'" +"\'"

#1: in_query = f"(area[name={ags_name}];) ->.a;(area[postal_code={plz}];) ->.b;way(area.a)(area.b)[name={str_name}];"
#2: in_query = """(area[name="Braunschweig"];) ->.a;(area[postal_code="38114"];) ->.b;way(area.a)(area.b)[name="Celler Heerstraße"];"""
#3: in_query = f"""(area[name={ags_name}];) ->.a;(area[postal_code={plz}];) ->.b;way(area.a)(area.b)[name={str_name}];"""


arcpy.OSMQueryToolbox.GetOSMDataExpert(in_query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the query. It works totally fine with f-strings. The right query is

> in_query = f"""(area[name="{ags_name}"];) ->.a;(area[postal_code="{plz}"];) ->.b;way(area.a)(area.b)[name="{str_name}"];"""

I just forgot the " before and after the key value.